# Java sql remove brackets

Tags: java, sql, regex, sqlite

This is the output im recieving:

```
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES ([J1, Sorter, Paris)
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES (J2, Punch, Rome)
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES (J3, Reader, Athens)
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES (J4, Console, Athens)
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES (J5, Collator, London)
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES (J6, Termninal, Oslo)
INSERT INTO [ J] VALUES (J7, Tape, London])
```

As you can see i have a [ at the beginning and a ] at the end and i don't know what is causing it? how can i remove it? i have tried regex it with .replace("[ ]",""); where i belive the problem is occuring but to no avail.

Code for inserting:

```
  if (state == 3||!tableLineScanner.hasNextLine()){
                        try{
                            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                            Connection conn = null;
                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
                            //TODO Input values goes here
                            tableName =""+tableNames;
                            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                            String query = tableValues + "";
                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tableName);
                            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            query.replaceAll("[ ]","");
                            tableName =""+tableNames;
                            tableName.replaceAll("[ ]","");
                            String[] splittedOutput = query.split(", ");
                            int valuesOnLine = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < splittedOutput.length; i++) {
                                if (i % valuesOnLine == 0) {
                                    System.out.print("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (");
                                }
                                System.out.print(splittedOutput[i]);
                                if (i % valuesOnLine == valuesOnLine - 1) {
                                    System.out.println(")");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.print(", ");
                                }
                            }
                            tableNames.clear();
                            tableValues.clear();
                            tableFields.clear();
                        }
                        catch (SQLException ex){
                            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
                        }
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get more problems if you have more than one element in `tableNames`.  Do you intend to just use the first table name?  Or to iterate through `tableNames` using all of them?  Right now, you're converting `tableNames` to a String of the form `[element1, element2, element3]` which is almost certainly not what you want.

If you did want to just remove the `[]` characters though, you need to write something like `replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")` because `[]` are special characters in a regular expression.

Comment: Im having an array with element1,element2,element3 but i cant seem to get rid of the [] even with your replaceAll code

Comment: I don't think you have an array.  You have either a `List` or a `Set` of some type.  If it's a list, I recommend calling `get(0)` on it to get the value that you want.

Comment: If your solution is different from what I said, can you please post it as an answer?  For the benefit of anyone else who has this problem in the future?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to remove the brackets was using by configuring splittedOutput to this:

```
System.out.print(splittedOutput[i].replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```